# DataTables - Load data from pre-defined JSON

Tags: arrays, json, datatables

I have a problem pointing dataTable to the right spot in the JSON. I receive a nested array:

```
{
"status": "ok",
"count": "7",
"msg ": "Operation Successful",
"data": [{
    "contactHasServiceArea": true,
    "issueCategories": [{
            "id": "8",
            "description": "Finance"
        },
        {
            "id": "9",
            "description": "Housing"
        },
        {
            "id": "10",
            "description": "International"
        }
    ],
    "cases": [{
        "id": 31645,
        "client_name": "Matthew",
        "issue": "Assessment Completion",
        "referral": null,
        "opened_date": "10\/07\/2017",
        "case_status": "Open"
    }, {
        "id": 31668,
        "client_name": "Fanky ",
        "issue": "Complex",
        "referral": null,
        "opened_date": "01\/07\/2017",
        "case_status": "Open"
    }]
}]
```

}

How do I point to the "cases" object? I'm sure this is simply, but I'm confused by the many options in the dataTables config.

I tried variations of data, dataSrc as well as data.cases or just cases, etc.
Thanks

```
 $('#cases_table').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "ajax/getCases",
        "dataSrc"   : "data.cases",
        "data"      : "cases",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "client_name" },
            { "data": "issue" },
            { "data": "referral" },
            { "data": "opened_date" },
            { "data": "case_status" }
            ]
    } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure like this:

```
$('#cases_table').DataTable( {
  "ajax": {
     "url": "ajax/getCases",
     "dataSrc"   : "data.cases"
   },
   "columns": [
       { "data": "client_name" },
       { "data": "issue" },
       { "data": "referral" },
       { "data": "opened_date" },
       { "data": "case_status" }
    ]
  } );
```

datasrc points into the returns json. Remove the data option.

Comment: that's what I thought, too, but makes no difference. It just says no data in table

Comment: Did you try reconfiguring the Ajax option as I did in my answer?

Comment: It works! The error was on the server which didn't recognize the auth of the client and sent empty JSON. Thanks !!!